# OCaml Unbound value enf

Tags: ocaml, unbound

I have a question about using a local function in a global function.
I tried to write the function which appears in the picture, but an error said

> unbound value of f

It's strange that this error occurs. It should not appear because I defined the definition of the function `enf` in `affichage`.

Here is a picture of a relevant part of my code:

[image: click here to see the picture of program]

What can be the reason of this error?

Comment: You'd better try to reduce your function you are trying to write, and provide the error on SO with the exact piece of code that is going wrong with the exact error message you got as well.

Comment: Try to make a [mcve] and post your code as text instead of as an image. You are much more likely to get an answer if you make it easy for potential answerers to do so. See also [ask].

Comment: Please post the code of your program in your question, instead of providing a link to a painting of it.

Answer (score 1):

`enf` is not defined when `affichage` is defined, so since the body of `affichage` refers to `enf`, this results in an unbound value error. In order to have [mutually recursive functions](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/labels.html#Mutually-recursive-functions), you'll need something of the form

```
let rec affichage (* ... *) =
  (* ... *)
and enf (* ... *) =
  (* ... *)
in
  (* ... *)
;;
```

Comment: thank you i will check the documentation that you give me